# MongoDB not updating upon using $set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to update a score on my database.

```
        await database.client.db("lazer").collection("scores").updateOne({id: req.params.id }, { $set : {
        accuracy: score.accuracy,
        build_id: 6519,
        ended_at: date,
        legacy_perfect: score.legacy_fc,
        max_combo: score.max_combo,
        mods: score.mods,
        passed: score.passed,
        pp: score.pp,
        rank: score.rank,
        replay: false,
        statistics: score.statistics,
        total_score: score.total_score,
        completed: score.completed,
        type: score.type,
    }
```

so yeah i don't really know what to do at this point i've been trying to work things out, but the documents don't want to update. :(

Comment: Could you include an example of the document you're trying to update? It could be that the field name (`id` vs `_id`) or the field type.

Comment: i'm trying to update a score document that is stored with "id" as parameter that i give before-hand to the client. now i'm trying to update the document with the id that is given as a parameter

Comment: Is the value of `req.params.id` what you expect? Is the `id` field a `String` or `ObjectId`?

Comment: it's a string that gets parsed to a number since the "id" field is a number

Comment: The value of `req.params.id` would be a string, so if the `id` field is a number it won't be matched.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i made it clear that "req.params.id" gets parsed as a number. Either way i used the findOneAndUpdate method which works like a charm